# thinking a $p$-adic integer in different ways

Tags: p-adic-number-theory

In Serre's course in arithmetic, $p$-adic integers are defined as follows: let $A_n:=\mathbb{Z}/p^n\mathbb{Z}$. There are natural (ring) homomorphisms $\phi_n:A_n\rightarrow A_{n-1}$. The ring of $p$-adic integers is the inverse limit of the system $(A_n,\phi_n)$. Then the author says

> By definition, a $p$-adic integer is a sequence $(\cdots, x_3,x_2,x_1)$ with $x_i\in A_i$ and $\phi_n(x_n)=x_{n-1}$.

On the other hand, the formally written *expression* for a $p$-adic integer is of the form $a_0 + a_1 p + a_2p^2 + \cdots $ with $0\le a_i<p$. Here, $a_i$'s are independent, whereas, in the definition of Serre, the coordinates $x_i$ are successively dependent through homomorphisms $\phi_i$'s.

I do not understand how to write a formally written $p$-adic integer as a sequence expressed by Serre?

Comment: $x_i$ is the $p$-adic integer $\bmod p^i$. You consider only the first $i$ digits.

Comment: The condition $\phi_n(x_n)=x_{n-1}$ means that in the case of addition or multiplication, you need to go one digit to left if the summation pr production exceed $p^n$. Also note that the coordinates $x_i$ are not only digits $a_i$, but $a_ip^i$.

Comment: In your notation, $x_i = a_0 + a_1p + \cdots + a_{i-1}p^{i-1}$, so there is no contradiction between having independently chosen $a_i$ and dependent $x_i$.